# Calling native DLL functions that return (and accept) pointers to structs

Tags: c#, dll

I've got a "native" DLL with some nice functions that can return (and accept) pointers to data which is formatted according to particular C structs.

In my C# program I don't care about the struct internals, I just want to get and pass them from/to the native functions. I've already managed to pinvoke the functions inside the DLL.
For to pointers, I've thought of using void* (as a "pointer-to-unknown"), since I really don't care the internal fields of the pointed structs, I just need to store and use the pointers to pass it to the DLL library functions.

But using void* for many different kinds of data makes my code unreadable! Is there any way in C# to typedef void* some_nicer_type_t ? Or to do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using `IntPtr` instead.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx):

> A platform-specific type that is used
>   to represent a pointer or a handle.

This may ultimately aid you in writing non-`unsafe` code, too.

**EDIT:**

To address your desired needs as reiterated in comment to this question, one thing I might suggest (though not proposing this to be ideal) is to define a `struct` or `class` which is essentially a wrapper around a pointer:

```
public struct TypedPointer
{
    public IntPtr UnderlyingPointer;
}
```

As you yourself bring up, this may lead to wrapping even more code in order to have it all conform to the usage and aesthetics of usage that you want.

Comment: Thanks, but IntPtr keeps on being IntPtr for everything. It can be cleaner, but to me it's messy and meaningless just like void*. I tried typedef IntPtr someothertype_t but it doesn't compile. How can I just define new types? I guess I should use some workaround like wrapping IntPtr inside some object and then use wrappers for the functions as well. Uhm, annoying.

Comment: @Giacomo: Updated my answer, but really it just overlaps with your updated comment.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and attention. This solution is the best that can be done.

Comment: if you just want to refer to a `IntPtr` by another name, `using TypedPointer = System.IntPtr` works too.

Comment: That is a possibility, though tedious to be done throughout files as required - therefore isn't really 'typing' anything within the project, per se.

Comment: "using", as far as i know, works only within the same file. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll however go for the wrapping solution

Answer (score 1):

> IntPtr

is the way to go.
Only area which you have to be careful is the memory management. Unsafe or not - C# needs a reference otherwise it will be sooner or later garbage-collected - potentially also when one of the external dlls uses it. Thus you need to ensure that the reference to the IntPtr is kept as long as needed also on the C# side.